# how to generate a document with data from a database for printing purposes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm developing a system to generate a water bill for a local area.In it i need to print out the bill from using the data from the database.It would be a greatly appreciated if someone could explain me how to generate & print the bill in vb.net. Thanks in advance.

[image: For example something like this.....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Crystal Reports](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1055).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed *crystal reports* would do it, have a look at this:

[How to Print a Crystal Report Programmatically in ASP.NET?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CRPrinting10062006161454PM/CRPrinting.aspx)